# True or not: We should always use proper capitalization and never put whole sentences in all-uppercase

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

True or not: We should always use proper capitalization and never put whole sentences in all-uppercase. If we must do so, we should use CSS for this task."

Should we use the CSS property `text-transform` for other cases if we need them?

(Note that I'm not talking about HTML tags, I’m talking about text content)

Links to read:

- http://blog.mauveweb.co.uk/2009/01/14/dont-use-uppercase-in-html/
- http://www.webaim.org/techniques/fonts/#caps

Comment: do you mean all lowercase with no capitalization at all, OR DO YOU MEAN LOWER-CASE INSTEAD OF ALL UPPER CASE?

Comment: I think @jitendra meant this in regard to tag names.

Comment: @Pekka i hope that, else it will be a joke.

Comment: @Amr not necessarily if he comes from a language background that doesn't know capitalization. I *think* (although I'm not sure, will have to check) that only latin alphabet based languages have capitals.

Comment: @Close voters: *Wow* what a narrow definition of programming. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @jitendra I amended my answer.

Comment: Just to set this straight: In German, *every* noun is capitalized. You can't just make it all lowercase and say: 'oh, but the screen readers would choke, if we made correct capitalization.' You would be grilled (and rightly so) by lots of people, most likely containing your customers. That's like, in Arab, to say we only use the isolated form, because the combined forms are not SEO friendly. Every language has its rules (like Pekka said), and one should respect them (that *includes* English capitalization rules).

Comment: I'm joining the re-open bandwagon.  It's a stupid question sure, but it **is programming related**.

Comment: Me not. IMHO it's a 'I'd like to get lapidated by linguists' kind of question, and I don't see the relevance for programming.

Comment: I updated my answer again. I think I understand the background of the question now. The point is that if words are in ALL CAPS, screen readers may spell them letter by letter, instead of pronouncing them as a full word. I could well see this happening in a screen reader.

Comment: “I head Screen reader spell letter by letter if we use UPPERCASE.” These are the kind of details that are useful to include in your question in the first place.

Comment: If case is part of style, use it in CSS. If case is part of content, use it in HTML. Simple as that.

Comment: This is about the content of a web page, *not* about how to transform to upper or lowercase.  This question is not programming related.  Compare "what should my alt text contain" to "how can I add alt text using language X or library Y".

Comment: After the last edit it seems that jitendra and we (= commenters and answerers) talked at cross-purposes. It was not about putting all text in lowercase, but about *not* putting any text in uppercase for style reasons. As such, my above comments are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not talking about HTML TAG i'm talking about text content? I head Screen reader spell letter by letter if we use UPPERCASE.
>
> my question was "Should we always use lowercase text in web page's content?" and use css text-transform for other cases if we need.

Just use natural text, as you did in your SO question. Screen readers will generally read ALL UPPERCASE as individual letters, as such text is generally an acronym (it'll likely vary from reader to reader - some handle things more intelligently than others, and may be able to figure out that a whole sentence isn't likely to be an acronym).

You don't have to *lowercase* every letter, though - a screen reader shouldn't have any problem with "This Is A Sentence."

UPPERCASE text that isn't an acronym should be done with CSS's `text-transform: uppercase;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `text-transform: uppercase` does not always stop screenreaders spelling out letters: it depends on the browser. A friend and I experimented with 5 screenreaders across 3 operating systems (VoiceOver on iOS, NVDA, Jaws and Narrator on Windows, and Orca on Gnome) and tried multiple voices when possible (eSpeak NG, SAPI5, Eloquence, Core Voices) and different browsers (Safari, Edge, IE, Firefox, Chrome), all current versions as of 2020. In nearly all cases, Edge and IE read words properly under text-transform, but other browsers did not: short words can still be spelled out.

Answer (score 13):

Huh? For normal text? That sounds like a ridiculous idea to me. Every language has its rules about what's lowercase and what's uppercase. Why would one want to divert from that?

**Update**: Sorry Jitendra, I didn't read your update closely. Now *this*

> I head Screen reader spell letter by letter if we use UPPERCASE.

could well be - say, for USA to be spelled like U S A. I could imagine some screen readers do this. *But* this would only mean not to put words in ALL CAPS - which is a rule you would want to follow anyway.

Having all text in lowercase and uppercasing the right words through `text-transform`, you would have to put a CSS class on every word that needs to be capitalized - extremely cumbersome, would result in horribleHTML soup, and wouldn't make sense. Just use normal capitalization, and don't use all caps.

Comment: @jitendra: You should include the links in the question. Please correct me, if I'm wrong, but after reading both, I tend to interpret your original question like this: "True or not: We should always use proper capitalization and never put whole sentences in all-uppercase. If we must do so, we should use CSS for this task." My previous interpretation, however, was: "True or not: We should put text *always* in all-lowercase, because capitalization is not supported by some software."

Answer (score 8):

You should write content of a page with proper grammar, spelling, and capitalization just as you would in an essay. Navigation and logos should start with an Uppercase (or if it's a name, the proper spelling for the name, e.g. iPhone, not Iphone or IPhone.) Only use CSS capitalization for stylization. So, if you want your site's name to be in all caps (MY WEBSITE) use CSS to make it all caps, but in the HTML make sure it's proper (My Website).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

It's generally a good idea to concentrate on what's easy for people to read. Almost always, for almost all sorts of information presentation, conventional typographic rules for the language of the site are appropriate, and you should not do anything different without having a really good reason.

Answer (score 2):

The W3C states that all XHTML elements and attribute names should be in lowercase:

> XHTML documents must use lower case
>   for all HTML element and attribute
>   names. This difference is necessary
>   because XML is case-sensitive e.g.
>   `<li>` and `<LI>` are different tags.

As for web page content in between tags, of course it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes this too is true, for XHTML.  I don't believe that HTML5 cares.

Comment: Right, but not the **content**, just (as the quote says) the names of elements and attributes.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite XHTML5 is also dead.

Comment: he is talking about content.  you are correct, but answering the wrong question

Comment: @ceejayoz: in what sense is XHTML5 dead? It’s in the spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#html-vs-xhtml

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Sorry, I confused XHTML2 with XHTML5. NM me!

Comment: @ceejayoz: :) easily done. If you flip the 5 upside down it sort of looks like a 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Jaws does not spell out words if they are recognized as English words. FOR EXAMPLE "THIS IS PRONOUNCED NORMALLY." sounds the same as "This is pronounces normally." When dealing with abbreviations capitalization matters. For example "usa" is pronounced phonetically as one syllable. “USA” is pronounced as “u s a” Made up words tend to be pronounced the same regardless of capitalization, for example “FDIOSUF” is pronounced the same as “Fdiosuf”

Comment: One example problem word is the word "us".  When written in capitals i.e. US this can be an abbreviation for United States so can be spelled out.  But when written in capitals as part of an all capitals sentence, for example PLEASE HELP US, it should be read as a word rather than an abbreviation, but screen-readers can get this wrong (as of 2020).

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with screen readers. For actual *content*, you should use normal capitalization. For element names and attributes, you **must** use lower case if you're using XHTML, because it's case-sensitive and the spec says the tag names and attribute names are lower case. These are two completely different things (content vs.markup).

**Edit** Re your edited question: You should avoid *incorrect* use of ALL UPPER CASE TEXT (that would be an example of incorrect use), because screen readers may well spell that out on the theory that it's an acronym like HTML or W3C. But *not* doing ALL CAPS is not the same as doing all lower case. Use initial capitals at the beginnings of sentences, etc. Don't use ALL CAPS for emphasis, use `<em>` (or `<strong>`, depending on the type of emphasis). Doing so marks up your text semantically, which actually *helps* the screen reader do its job (by allowing it to put emphasis where it should be put).

Answer (score -2):

yes you should, if you would like to modify the text letters use the css property text-transform http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_text-transform.cfm

Comment: what? why would somone want to do this? not enless you want the whole block of text to be caps

Comment: WTF? You can modify any case of letters using text-transform, there's no need (nor any good reason) to make them lowercase prior!

Comment: lol, are you serious? well maybe i didn't understand the question right :(